# PHP header function not redirecting the page

Tags: php, redirect

I have been using the `header()` to redirect for several pages, but in this case it is not redirecting.

In this case, I will have a blank page as if the header part of the code is not working, the file path is correct to so I am not sure what could be the issue here.

The code:

```
<?php

//start session management
session_start();
//connect to the database
require 'connection.php';
// Require function
require_once "../model/functions_cars.php";
// Fetch the data required
$carID = $_GET['carID'];
$sold = $_GET['sold'];

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$username = $_SESSION['user'] || $_SESSION['admin'] || $_SESSION['disabled'];
global $conn;
$sql = "SELECT userID FROM sport_cars.user WHERE username = :username";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
$result3 = $statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
$userID = $result3;
//call the buy_car() function
$result = buy_car($carID, $sold);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Query error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}

global $conn;
$sql = "INSERT INTO sport_cars.sold_cars (carID, userID, date) VALUES (:carID, :userID, :date)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':carID', $carID);
$statement->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
$statement->bindValue(':date', $date);
$result2 = $statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
return $result2;
// header("location: ../cart_buy.php");
//  Redirect the browser window back to the add cart page

if (!$result2) {
    echo "Query error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
} else {
    // Redirect the browser window back to the add cart page
    header("location: ../cart_buy.php");
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have `return $result2;` before the header?  This stops the rest of the code being executed.

Comment: You are mixing APIs. `mysqli_error` can't be used with PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` statement is being called and preventing the rest of the code from executing, you need your if statement to still execute for `$result2`, and then trigger the `header()` redirect after.

This should work fine.

```php
<?php

session_start(); // Start session management.
require 'connection.php'; // Connect to the database.

// Require function
require_once "../model/functions_cars.php";

// Fetch the data required.
$carID = $_GET['carID'];
$sold = $_GET['sold'];

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$username = $_SESSION['user'] || $_SESSION['admin'] || $_SESSION['disabled'];

$sql = "SELECT userID FROM sport_cars.user WHERE username = :username";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
$statement->execute();
$userID = $statement->fetchColumn();

//call the buy_car() function
$result = buy_car($carID, $sold);

$sql = "INSERT INTO sport_cars.sold_cars (carID, userID, date) VALUES (:carID, :userID, :date)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':carID', $carID);
$statement->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
$statement->bindValue(':date', $date);
$statement->execute();
// return $result2; <- move this somewhere else, this is what is causing your header() below to not redirect.

// Redirect the browser window back to the add cart page
header("Location: ../cart_buy.php");
```